# Output Django Model as Table

Tags: django, html-table, model

I have a view definition that (attempts to) outputs a model as a table. This is what I have so far:

```
def output_table(request):
    output = My_Model()
    return render_to_response('outputtable.html', {'output': output})
```

Here's the HTML for outputtable.html:

```
<html>
<table>
    {{ output.as_table }}
</table>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesn't work. Now, it's passing the model correctly, because if I change `My_Model()` to `My_Model.objects.all()` and then output it as simply `{{ output }}` then it shows me what I would see in the Django shell.

Answer (score 2):

So what you need to do is the following:

1) add

`from django.forms import ModelForm` to your models.py

2) add

```
class My_Model_Form(ModelForm):  
           class Meta:  
               model = My_Model
```

3) in your views.py, change `output = My_Model()` to `output = My_Model_Form()`

Now you are all set. So the trick is to inherit your Form from your original model.

Comment: If you're rendering an existing model instance, do `output = My_Model_Form(instance=my_model)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to output one specific model, change your template to something like

```
<tr>
  <td>Name:</td>
  <td>{{ output.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

for all the fields you care about. If this is something you want to be able to do for any arbitrary model in your app, take a look at this [snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/843/). That would provide you with a fields collection to loop over.

Answer (score 1):

OMG this is old but [Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/generic-views/#list-detail-generic-views) seem to be a good fit for this problem, for me at least. A List detail view should help me get running faster. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `models.Model` class doesn't have a method `as_table()` like the `forms.ModelForm` class does.

My solution was to also use template tags. I went with an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags).

`myapp/templatetags/model_helpers.py`

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()


@register.inclusion_tag('myapp/model_table.html', takes_context=True)
def model_as_table(context, model_key=None, model_table_attrs_key=None):

    if model_key is None:
        model_key = 'object'

    if model_table_attrs_key is None:
        model_table_attrs_key = 'model_table_attrs'

    try:
        attrs = context[model_table_attrs_key]
    except KeyError:
        attrs = context[model_key]._meta.get_all_field_names()

    table_context = {'rows': []}
    for attr in attrs:
        try:
            value = str(getattr(context[model_key], attr))
            if value:
                table_context['rows'].append({'attr': attr,
                                              'value': context[model_key][attr]})
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        # Needs a way to display many_to_many fields.
        except StopIteration:
            pass

    return table_context
```

`myapp/templates/myapp/model_table.html`

```
{% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        <td class="name">{{ row.attr }}</td>
        <td class="field">{{ row.value }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`myapp/templates/myapp/outputtable.html`

```
{% load model_helpers %}

<table>
    {% model_as_table %}
</table>
```

With this implementation you can pass which model's attributes you want to display and in which order.

`myapp/views.py`

```
def output_table(request):
    output = My_Model()
    return render_to_response('outputtable.html',
                              {'output': output, 'model_table_attrs': ['attr1', 'attr2']})
```

I also like this cleanly separate html and python code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method `as_table` on a model instance (`MyModel()`)or on Querysets (`MyModel.objects.all()`). You may have seen `as_table` as [the forms method `as_table`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#as-table). You don't have a form there.

If you want to print a model instance/ a queryset as a table, you will have to design it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that worked for my specific need which renders any simple model's data into table rows. Add the following filter into `templatetags/your_tags_file.py` (don't forget the __init__.py file in the templatetags folder):

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def as_table(model):
    ret = ""
    for name in model._meta.get_all_field_names():
        try:
            field = str(getattr(model, name))
            if field:
                ret += '<tr><td class="name">'+name+'</td><td class="field">'+field+'</td></td>'
        except AttributeError:
            pass
    return ret
```

In the template now you can just do:

```
{% load your_tags_file %}
<table>
    {{output|as_table|safe}}
</table>
```

This will render the model in a simple table for you. You can easily add any desired `thead` and `tbody` logic as you see fit by modifying the logic of how `ret` is generated. Hope this helps someone.