# How to get model field value from model and field in django template?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I would like to create a template for printing values of my models in table. This supposed to work for various models.

I was thinking that when I put all objects of specific model into rows and specific fields of that model into columns I could get values in cells. This is my idea:

```
# views.py

def users(request):
    all_users = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
    fieldnames = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'department']
    fields = [all_users[0]._meta.get_field(field) for field in fieldnames]
    context = {
        'rows': all_users,
        'columns': fields,
    }
    return render(request, 'table.html', context=context)
```

```
# table.html

<table>
<tr>
    {% for col in columns %}
    <th>{{ col.verbose_name }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for row in rows %}
<tr>
    {% for col in columns %}
    <td>{{ row|col }}</td>            # or row.col or row:col
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

How can I get there? Is this the right way of thinking and doing? Or should I somehow manage the data before rendering?

Comment: Does this answer your question? - https://stackoverflow.com/a/26614950/4996863

Comment: It kinda did helped me. Look at my solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to create custom template tag.

in `users/templatetags/table_tags.py`

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def value_from_model(model, field):
    return getattr(model, field)
```

in `users/views.py`

```
def users(request):
    all_users = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
    fieldnames = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'department']
    fields = [all_users[0]._meta.get_field(field) for field in fieldnames]
    context = {
        'rows': all_users,
        'cols': fields,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/table.html', context=context)
```

in `users/templates/users/table.html`

```html
{% load table_tags %}

<table>
    <tr>
        {% for col in cols %}
        <th>{{ col.verbose_name }}</th>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% for row in rows %}
    <tr>
        {% for col in cols %}
        <td>{{ row|value_from_model:col.name }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Hope someone would find this useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your customUser model has the same name of the fieldnames

## views.py

````
```python
def users(request):
        all_users = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
        list_colmns = ['id', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'department']
        list_rows = []
        for user in all_users:
            list_rows.append(
                [user.id, user.email, user.first_name, user.last_name, user.department])
        return render(request, 'table.html', {"list_rows": list_rows, "list_colmns": list_colmns})
```
````

## Template

```
<table>
<tr>
    {% for column in list_colmns %}
    <th>{{ column }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% for row in list_rows %}
<tr>
    {% for cell in row %}
        <td>{{ cell }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, @Luiz. Thanks for your answer. I may not made it clear, but I want to use this template on a few models that have different fields, so I can't call value explicitly like you did in your solution.

Comment: Hello my friend, i understand now your question and i edit my answer, hope this works for you.